# Compactness of infinite union under these conditions

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Assume I have an infinite sequence $(S_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of sets $S_k\subset \mathbb R^n$, assume that all the $S_k$ are compact with respect to the topology induced by some metric $d:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.
The infinite union $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N} S_k$ is not necessarely compact. But what could one conclude if all the sets $S_k$ have a common point (i.e. $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N} S_k \neq \emptyset$)  and they are all subset of a given bounded set $\bar S$?

What if all the $S_k$ are distributed around a given point? (for instance the origin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion I want to jump to is that the infinite union is compact.  But, that is not true.

Suppose $S_n = \{1,\frac1n\}$

and $\bar S = \{\frac1n: \forall n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$

$\bar S$ is compact.

$\bigcap S_k = \{1\}$ i.e. non-empty.

There exists a sequence $\in\bigcup S_k$ that converges to $0.$

$0 \notin \bigcup S_k$

$\bigcup S_k$ is not compact.

Comment: I like this because it highlights the point that the condition that all the sets intersect a mutual point is really not that hard to overcome. Just take a counterexample without that condition and then take the disjoint union of all those sets with some point not in the closure of their union. (Also it works in 1d, which my example does not).

Comment: Thanks, thats a pretty nice example... Which conditions in you hopinion would suffices to conclude compactness? Maybe something related to the cardinality of $S_n$? By the way can you please explain to a layman why $S_n$ is compact in your example?

Comment: A set is compact if every open cover has a finite sub-cover.  Whatever ball covers 0, covers all $S_n$ greater than some N.  Leaving a finite number of points $S_n$ still to cover.  It is one of the classics to demonstrate the concept of compactness.

Comment: What you are really looking for is for your union of sets to be closed.

Comment: yes definitely, so a stronger condition should avoid the possibility of sets which have a sort of "accumolation point" which is not in the union, for example in $\mathbb R$ If I take $S_n = [-\dfrac{n-1}{n},\dfrac{n-1}{n}]$ then that's another sequence with will give me problems right? because $(\dfrac{n-1}{n})_n$ is a subsequence of the infinite union which converges outside (in $1$). Is that right?

Comment: I agree, the union of sets in your example would not be compact.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $S_k=[-k,k]$

[edit after the question was changed]

If you want $S_k\subset\tilde{S}$ for some compact $\tilde{S}$ then let $S_k$ be the unit line segment intersecting the origin of the plane at angle $\theta=2\pi/k$.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot an additional cobstraint. Just added. All the sets are subsets of a given bounded set